# How to infer the lifetime that Lifetime annotations in method(or function) definitions?

Tags: rust

```rust
struct V<'a> {
    s: &'a mut String,
    v: Vec<&'a String>
}

impl<'a, 'b> V<'a> {
    pub fn set(&mut self, s: &'b String){
        // self.s = s;
        self.s.push_str(s);
        self.v.push(s);
    }
}
```

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:68:9
   |
64 | impl<'a, 'b> V<'a> {
   |      --  -- lifetime `'b` defined here
   |      |
   |      lifetime `'a` defined here
...
68 |         self.v.push(s);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'b` must outlive `'a`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`
```

But the `self.s.push_str(s);` is OK. Their function signatures are the same (`fn xxx(&mut self, &...)`). What is the reason?

I read this article (2094-nll) over and over again. Seemingly understanding but not understanding.
I want to improve my Rust programming habits by learning NLL. However, I'm still very confused.

Answer (score 1):

> Their function signatures are the same( fn xxx(&mut self, &...) ).

Let's examine that claim.

#### 1. [`String::push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str)

```rust
pub fn push_str(&mut self, string: &str)
```

It requires a `&str`, aka a slice of (utf-8 encoded) bytes, with no additional lifetime requirements.

`String` has an implicit [`Deref` conversion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref-for-String) to `&str`.

For our supplied argument (`s: &'b String`), this results in a `&'b str`. We can call `push_str` with no problem, as it has no lifetime requirements for it's argument.

#### 2. [`Vec::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push)

```rust
pub fn push(&mut self, value: T)
```

which, when `T` is bound to `&'a String` (the generic argument for your `Vec`) becomes

```rust
pub fn push(&mut self, value: &'a String)
```

It requires a `&'a String`, aka a reference to a
`String` object with a lifetime at least as long as `'a` .

Our supplied argument is once again `s: &'b String`.
The lifetime `'b` has makes no claim about it's relation to `'a`, so the compiler can't assume that it is longer. Therefore the compiler refuses to accept a `s: &'b String` in place of an `s: &'a String`.

One fix for this (as the compiler kindly suggested) is to require such a bound on the lifetime `'b`:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b: 'a> V<'a> {
    pub fn set(&mut self, s: &'b String){
        self.s.push_str(s);
        self.v.push(s);
    }
}
```

Or, as it would be more commonly written (as `'b` has nothing to do with our `Vec`):

```rust
impl<'a> V<'a> {
    pub fn set<'b: 'a>(&mut self, s: &'b String){
        self.s.push_str(s);
        self.v.push(s);
    }
}
```

Finally, the lifetime `'b` is actually completely unnecessary here.
You could just use `'a` everywhere. (For function arguments, lifetimes are always the minimum bound).

```rust
impl<'a> V<'a> {
    pub fn set(&mut self, s: &'a String){
        self.s.push_str(s);
        self.v.push(s);
    }
}
```

( [Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c67d2b606110eb1849fbb47f57db299) )